# Setting correct apache environment for Pervasive v10 ODBC client Centos 6.2

Tags: php, apache, odbc, centos, pervasive

I have installed the Pervasive v10 linux 32 bit ODBC client (64 bit is not available) on Centos 6.2 64 bit. I can successfully use isql to connect to a remote data source. However, when attempting to connect via PHP with:

> $connect = odbc_connect("demodata", "", "");

I get the same error isql gave me before I got my environment variables correct.

> Warning: odbc_connect(): SQL error: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/usr/local/psql/lib/odbcci.so' : file not found, SQL state 01000 in SQLConnect in /var/www/html/pst.php on line 2

I've tried adding the env variables to /etc/sysconfig/httpd:

> export PVSW_ROOT=/usr/local/psql
>   export PATH=$PVSW_ROOT/bin:/bin:/usr/bin
>   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$PVSW_ROOT/lib:$PVSW_ROOT/lib64:$PVSW_ROOT/bin:/usr/lib
>   export MANPATH=$PVSW_ROOT/man:$MANPATH
>   export BREQ=$PVSW_ROOT/lib
>   export LD_BIND_NOW=1

I've added apache to the pvsw group

> /usr/bin/gpasswd -a apache pvsw

Comment: After adding the env variables an the pvsw group, are you getting the same error?

Comment: Yes. PHP is giving me the same odbcci.so file not found error so i still have something wrong. phpinfo shows all the variables there and correct though so not sure what's wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that Apache and PHP are running as a 64 bit process and can't load the 32 bit ODBC drivers.  I ran a quick install of CentOS 6.2 x64 and installed the default Apache and PHP and saw that it was a 64 bit version.  In a phpinfo page, I see "2.6.32-220.el6.x86_64" in the System portion.

Comment: I believe you are correct. Guess I'm starting over and setting this system up as 32bit. Thanks!